# ADF Query Panel with Table is not working

Tags: java, search, oracle11g, oracle-adf

I have two `JSF` pages `search.jsf` and `details.jsf` . In the `search.jsf`  I have an `ADF` search form. I just drag and drop the `View Criteria` as `ADF Query Panel with Table`. The result of user search will be shown in an `ADF table`. One of the column is a link that will direct the user to the `details.jsf`  to show the details of the selected row.

Every things works fine for the first time in the `search.jsf` . ***Problem*** is when the user go back from `details.jsf` to `search.jsf`   , The Search form is not working and only showing the previous selected row and after pressing default `search button` multiple times this **error message** is coming:

***Definition name 1 of type Attribute is invalid.***

---

I search in the internet. Some have similar problem says that there is problem in the attributes naming. I Checked nothing wrong, I even create new `view object` and still facing the same error. Also, I checked the `page definition`, `DataBindings` and `DataControl` files, no problems there.

***I am using Jdeveloper 11.1.2.3 with ADF Technology***

Comment: Have you checked that the attribute names are correctly mapped to those you've got in the view object query itself? Ensure that the name is a valid Java identifier with no spaces or punctuation. Also check the data types in of the DB columns and their corresponding attributes in the EO/VO

Answer (score 2):

That error generally indicates that there was a change in your View Objects attributes (query, names etc). Try creating a new search page, and see if it works. If it is OK, try to figure out what has been changed or in the worst case re-implement the searchPage. Take a look even in the VO used in "details.jsf" just to be sure. Tung